# Restart a python script within another python script

Tags: python-3.x, process, upstart

I have two python3 script, one which is a REST API and another one which can add resources to the first one.
Right now, they are working with upstart to make sure that they are always running smoothly. I would like to restart/reload one of them from the other and I'm not sure how without using subprocess popen to restart the second one.
Is there a better pythonic way to do it ?
The upstart pip package seems to be out-of-date.
Thank you